# how to setup modules in the Glue job script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, import-module

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzQArFt_On4

In this tutorial it's only using one python script, what is I need to import some functions from another python script? For example: `import script2`

I wonder what's the correct way to setup in Glue job? I've tried to store this script in s3 bucket and add the location in `editjob` -> `Security configuration, script libraries, and job parameters (optional)`
->`Python library path`, but it gave me error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script2`, does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the video tutorial there is no such import like `import script2`. So if you do this in your script and don't provide `script2.py` library, the import is going to fail with your the message you are getting.

How to write modules, is best explained in Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

The best way to start programming glue jobs is to **auto-generate** glue scripts by glue console. Then you can use the scripts generated as a starting point for customization. What's more you can setup [Glue Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint.html) or even run [glue locally](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/developing-aws-glue-etl-jobs-locally-using-a-container/) (or on ec2 instance) for learning and development purposes.